# ruby YAML array to JSON

Tags: arrays, ruby, json, yaml, markdown

I'm trying to convert rails translation .yml to .json.
in the .yml there is an array for presenting a list (markdown).
I'm using wti service for handling the locals and when pulling the translations I get this kind of yaml:

```
key:
  - value
  - value
  - value
```

but when I parsing this yaml to json it returns nothing (null in the json) unless I'm adding "|" to the start of the array like this:

```
key: |
  - value
  - value
  - value
```

wti gem doesn't add "|"...

ruby - 2.1.5
rails - 4.2

any ideas?

Comment: Could you please post your code to parsing `YAML` to `JSON`?

Answer (score 1):

It should have been the following. Assuming you copy paste the following to a file.

```
key:
- val1
- val2
- val3
```

Not sure if you added extra spaces or messed the indentation.

The JSON equivalent being:

```
{"key":["val1","val2","val3"]}
```

Comment: in the wti its as you wrote it, in the YAML the array has a tab indetation as should be.

Comment: Spacing is acceptable though, for the array definition.

Comment: the tabs are ok, it a must for the array

Comment: @NirAviel So, what's the problem ?

Comment: the problem is that when I converting the yaml into json the array is null

Answer (score 1):

solved!!

when working with webtranslateit the -

```
key:
    - value
    - value
```

is shown in the webtranslateit as array - [value,value]

and this array and how it written in the .yml is the problem.

I solve it by making the array a text block

```
- value
- value
```

also in the webtranslateit tool and like that the .yml becoming -

```
key: |-
    - value
    - value
```

Answer (score 0):

The yaml at the top looks valid

```
> y=YAML.load "key:
*   - value
*   - value
*   - value"
=> {"key"=>["value", "value", "value"]}

> puts y.to_json
{"key":["value","value","value"]}
```

The second YAML example turns all the following indented data into a string, so yes it's valid but it's probably not what you are looking for

```
> y=YAML.load "key: |
*   - value
*   - value
*   - value
* "
=> {"key"=>"- value\n- value\n- value\n"}

> puts y.to_json
{"key":"- value\n- value\n- value\n"}
```

Comment: I'm sure its valid, if I'll use it as regular translation in .erb/.haml/etc. it will work for sure but I need it as json and from there to use it as angular translation file and the conversion from .yml to .json is problematic.